# Populating a modal with data-id

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My goal is:

1. Click on a link
2. Open a modal
3. View information related to the row where the user clicked

Currently, my modal opens but it displays all my records, what I wish is simply to display the good record with the corresponding information.

I have a data-id on the `<a>` which is a unique identifier, I get it but I do not know how to use it later.

I also noticed with my Chrome debugger that when I open the modal it goes into `shown.bs.modal` but then it goes directly without executing what is in the function.

I do not know if this is really important in relation to my question but I would like to specify that my model contains a `List <_Event>`, `_Event` being a class that serves as a model for events.

Any help?

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetEventsDetails(int Zkp)
{
    ViewBag.sessionv = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("idMember");
    FileMakerRestClient client = new FileMakerRestClient(serverName, fileName, userName, password);
    var toFind = new Models.EventsLines { Zkp = 1392 };
    var results = await client.FindAsync(toFind);

    bool isEmpty = !results.Any();
    if (isEmpty)
    {
        return View();
    }

    Models.EventsLines oEventViewModel = new Models.EventsLines();

    oEventViewModel = results.ToList().First();

    Console.WriteLine(oEventViewModel);

    return PartialView(oEventViewModel);
}




 function GetEventsDetails(id) {

     $.get("@Url.Action("GetEventsDetails", "Events")/" + id,
         function (data) {
             $('.modal-body').html(data);
         })

     $('#myModal').show();

     }
```

Comment: Off topic: changing values in the `shown` event will give you a FOUC (or flash of previous value) - which is sucky UX.  Use `show.bs.modal` instead (or better, change the html before calling `.show()` as you're calling it via code).

Comment: You are running the same loop in myModal div @foreach (var item in Model._EventsLines)
                                {........ This will show all the record. You may need to call a Partial View which will show the selected id record inside the myModal div

Comment: @freedomn-m thx for your advance, i've change it from shown to show!

Comment: @Sonal Yep, its totally true for the foreach... I'm trying to do something like: foreach (var item in Model._EventsLines.Where(n => n.Zkp = idZkp) -- but it doesnt recognize idZkp offcourse... it would be so great if it could recognize it!

Comment: I'm searching a way to say to the foreach (in the modal) "hey, you need to show every item with Zkp = idZkp (idZkp is the data-id)

Comment: You have two options: 1) render everything then filter show/hide divs based on the id 2) make a server side call (via ajax) and only return what's needed (as recommended above).  If you use option 1 then you'll likely have problems with posting back to your controller unless you handle this manually (ie don't just submit the form).

Comment: Okey!! I managed to do it with a partial view as you suggered! I just have 2 questions: first, i'm supposed to pass an id (and with Chrome debugger i see that it works but when it comes to my controller's method is value is 0, i've edited my code to let you see if you know why? My second question is can i display 2 renderview in the same modal? Thx for your helps guys!

Comment: What i dont get is when i look in the Network of Chrome i see "https://localhost:44338/Events/GetEventsDetails/1392" which is good and supposed to let my "int Zkp" receive the 1392 value, right?